# как мне в данном приложении получить ответ в формате JSON

Tags: java, android, json, get

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextViewResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = "http://194.8.129.102:8888/number.json";
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mTextViewResult.setText(myResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Так в чём проблема-то? Код вполне себе выглядит рабочим.

Comment: у меня на сервере лежит файл number.json, мне нужно вытащить из него информацию в формате JSON, этот код просто возвращает всю инфу находящуюся на странице

Comment: Тогда три варианта:1) предпочтительный - изменить код сервера, чтобы он сразу отдавал то что нужно; 2) если сервер это и так умеет, то изменить запрос на понятный серверу; 3) познакомиться с библиотекой JSOUP и вытащить нужное из ответа с её помощью. Или парсить ответ вручную, регулярками и т.п... Ответ сервера и в какой вид хотите его привести вы нам не показали - поэтому конкретный способ парсинга мы вам не посоветуем.

Comment: содержимое в файле number.json: 
{
"number":"10"
}
мне нужно вытащить цифру 10, можете пожалуйста показать конкретный способ парсинга, то есть код

Comment: Можно применить `Retrofit`+`Gson` для удобства работы - почитайте статьи, в сети их достаточно. Для конкретно этого простого случая можно просто добавить к вашему коду `JSONObject o = new JSONObject(myResponse);` `int number = o.optInt("number");`

Comment: добавить или какую-то часть кода заменить? просто если я добавляю, то ничего не меняется...

Comment: Я вам показал как получить ваше число из ответа, а что вы будете с этим числом делать я понятия не имею. Хотите вывести на экран - выводите: `mTextViewResult.setText(Integer.toString(number));`

Comment: Спасибо большое!!))

Comment: Вы же и вытаскиваете весь текст судя по коду.

Comment: @Алексей сделайте просто модель данных POJO И вытаскивайте то что вам нужно. Ретрофит делает запрос асинхронно, поэтому RunOnUiThread не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно изрядно подтянуть себя по общим знаниям о сетях, http и правилах этого сообщества)

А по существу: если вы не хотите делать http сервер, а судя по всему вы этого не хотите, то не используйте OkHttp. Открывайте файл потоком, читайте и сохраняйте в строку. Строку парсите как json

```
URL url = new URL("http://194.8.129.102:8888/number.json");
InputStream in = url.openStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
do{
    int readed = in.read(buffer);
    if(readed <0)
        break;
    out.write(buffer, 0, readed);
} while(true)
String s = new String(out.toByteArray());
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(s);
```

Comment: у меня на сервере лежит файл number.json, нажимая на кнопку в приложении мне нужно чтобы то значение которое лежит в этом файле отображалось в "text view", я начинающий разработчик, и никогда этого не делал, поэтому я и обратился за помощью...

Comment: подскажите как мне для этого правильно написать код, и если знаете какую нибудь полезную литературу из интернета, посоветуйте пожалуйста чтобы я больше не задавал глупых вопросов))

Comment: Начните хотя бы с самоучителей, например https://startandroid.ru/ru/ Я не знаю что вам отвечать, т. к. вы не задаете вопроса. Задавайте конкретные вопросы, по конкретным проблема. Если вы вообще не знаете что спрашивать, то начните с задач попроще